# Use older versions of libraries on Dymola 2022

Tags: modelica, dymola

I'd like to use some new features of Dymola 2022, but the commercial library I use runs on Modelica Standard Library 3.2.3(MSL), so I have to replace the Design Library, Optimization Library, etc. with the older version. In the document of Dymola 2022, it gives information about using an older version of MSL, but not the other libraries. My question is:
Is it compatible between Dymola 2022 and the older version of all these libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried in Dymola 2022, but in Dymola 2021x it was possible to still use MSL 3.2.3 by doing these steps:

1. Copy the 3.2.3 version of MSL and other libraries from either the .zip installer or from an older Dymola installation to "C:\Program Files\Dymola 2021x\Modelica\Library" or 2022 instead of 2021x.
2. Change the setting in Dymola as shown below.
3. If this does not work, please contact your Dymola reseller, they can probably help to get MSL3 running also in Dymola 2022.

[image]

As discussed in the comments, parts of TPL are encrypted, so unfortunately you cannot run the conversion script yourself. The next release of TPL is expected in January 2022 and will be based on MSL4 (all Modelon commercial libraries will be based on MSL4 only). If it is urgent to update to MSL4 you can request an alpha version based on MSL4 today, but Modelon is only giving limited support for intermediate versions. Official releases see extended testing. If you are interested, please contact support@modelon.com

Comment: Should work in Dymola 2022, too. Note that besides MSL you might need other libraries as well

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can update your commercial libraries to MSL 4.0.0 and save the converted libraries to a new location. Dymola usually suggests the conversion when you load the libraries.

Comment: I am using the Thermal Power Library(TPL) from Modelon. When I try to load TPL with MSL 4.0, the warning of "Version inconsistency" says that TPL is a read-only package, could I pass around this limit?

Comment: Probably, parts of the TPL library are encrypted. If that's case, I'm not sure if it can be converted. Modelon should be able to answer that question.